# Python Fileconveyor Naming Issues

Tags: python, cloudfiles

Is there any way to get Fileconveyor(https://github.com/wimleers/fileconveyor) to create files on Rackspace CloudFiles without all of the directory information in the filename?

Example:
**Local directory**: 001
**Local filename**: 001-test.jpg
**CloudFiles container**: 001
**Uploaded filename**: 001/001-test.jpg
**Desired filename**: 001-test.jpg

Fileconveyor uploads a virtual directory called 001 into the 001 container and then prefixes the directory name to the filename.  I really want that virtual directory to not exist and just have the files uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where it actually puts the file up to cloudfiles you could add:

```
dir, file = os.path.split('foo/bar/baz.txt')
```

possibly before line 152 of fileconveyers/transporters/transport.py:

```
self.queue.put((src, dst, action, callback, error_callback))
```

where it adds the item to the queue.